# Anything wrong with my Fisher-Yates shuffle?

Tags: haskell, shuffle

Aware that when something seems too good to be true it usually is, I figured I would pose this question to hopefully flush out any gremlins. I reviewed the few related threads that I could find, but still my question lingers.

I am relatively new to Haskell, and in my experimentation I coded up a basic Fisher-Yates shuffle as shown below.

```
shuffle :: RandomGen g => [a] -> g -> ([a],g)
shuffle [] g0 = ([],g0)
shuffle [x] g0 = ([x],g0)
shuffle xs g0 = (x:newtail,g2)
  where (i,g1) = randomR (0, length $ tail xs) g0
        (xs1,x:xs2) = splitAt i xs
        (newtail,g2) = shuffle (xs1++xs2) g1
```

This implementation of course uses beaucoup memory for large lists, but it's fast - on my laptop avg 5s for 30M ints vs. Std C++ shuffle at 2.3s). In fact, it is much faster than other Haskell implementations have found elsewhere.(e.g., http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Random_shuffle)

Given other Haskell shuffles I've seen are both more complicated and slower, I am wondering whether the speedup/simplicity is simply my reward for being a unapologetic memory hog, or if I have missed some tiny but crucial detail that makes my algorithm biased. I have not tested extensively, but a preliminary look seems to show a uniform distribution of permutations.

I would appreciate the assessment of more eyes with more Haskell and/or shuffling experience. Many thanks in advance to all who take the time to reply.

Comment: Given that this calculates the length of the list on every iteration, I find the performance numbers you specify hard to believe. It's an O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: Are you perhaps timing the algorithm without actually forcing the entire result to be evaluated?

Comment: Show the timing code. A full shuffle of 30 million `Int`s with that code takes days to complete.

Comment: Almost wish I could go back in time and stop myself from posting this question. How embarrassing. :o Thanks everyone for not simply laughing me out of here!

Comment: "Almost wish I could go back in time and stop myself from posting this question." Why? You did learn something from it, didn't you? That's a good thing. (You also gained some rep from it, which isn't bad either.) So you fell into the trap of not sufficiently accounting for laziness, how embarrassing - as if that didn't happen to most of us. You're in good company there.

Comment: @DanielFischer Very true. My point was just that perhaps I should have spent more time thinking about it myself before asking the community. I'm not really regretting my question, but I learned as much about patience as I did about Haskell.

Comment: Figuring out something on one's own is more satisfying than being told? Yes, true. But if figuring it out would take too long, one should ask. Whether you would have figured it out yourself soon enough, only you can tell, if anybody.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's do some proper benchmarking.  Here's some code, with your shuffle renamed to `shuffle1`, and my personal favorite variant thrown in as `shuffle2`.

```
import System.Random

import Control.Monad

import Control.Monad.ST.Strict
import Data.STRef.Strict

import Data.Vector.Mutable

import Prelude as P

import Criterion.Main


shuffle1 :: RandomGen g => [a] -> g -> ([a], g)
shuffle1 [] g0 = ([],g0)
shuffle1 [x] g0 = ([x],g0)
shuffle1 xs g0 = (x:newtail,g2)
  where (i,g1) = randomR (0, P.length $ P.tail xs) g0
        (xs1,x:xs2) = P.splitAt i xs
        (newtail,g2) = shuffle1 (xs1++xs2) g1


shuffle2 :: RandomGen g => [a] -> g -> ([a], g)
shuffle2 xs g0 = runST $ do
    let l = P.length xs
    v <- new l
    sequence_ $ zipWith (unsafeWrite v) [0..] xs

    let loop g i | i <= 1 = return g
                 | otherwise = do
            let i' = i - 1
                (j, g') = randomR (0, i') g
            unsafeSwap v i' j
            loop g' i'

    gFinal <- loop g0 l
    shuffled <- mapM (unsafeRead v) [0 .. l - 1]
    return (shuffled, gFinal)


main = do
    let s1 x = fst $ shuffle1 x g0
        s2 x = fst $ shuffle2 x g0
        arr = [0..1000] :: [Int]
        g0 = mkStdGen 0
    -- make sure these values are evaluated before the benchmark starts
    print (g0, arr)

    defaultMain [bench "shuffle1" $ nf s1 arr, bench "shuffle2" $ nf s2 arr]
```

And so, let's see some results:

```
carl@ubuntu:~/hask$ ghc -O2 shuffle.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( shuffle.hs, shuffle.o )
Linking shuffle ...
carl@ubuntu:~/hask$ ./shuffle 
(1 1,[0, .. <redacted for brevity>])
warming up
estimating clock resolution...
mean is 5.762060 us (160001 iterations)
found 4887 outliers among 159999 samples (3.1%)
  4751 (3.0%) high severe
estimating cost of a clock call...
mean is 42.13314 ns (43 iterations)

benchmarking shuffle1
mean: 10.95922 ms, lb 10.92317 ms, ub 10.99903 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 193.8795 us, lb 168.6842 us, ub 244.6648 us, ci 0.950
found 1 outliers among 100 samples (1.0%)
variance introduced by outliers: 10.396%
variance is moderately inflated by outliers

benchmarking shuffle2
mean: 256.9394 us, lb 255.5414 us, ub 258.7409 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 8.042766 us, lb 6.460785 us, ub 12.28447 us, ci 0.950
found 1 outliers among 100 samples (1.0%)
  1 (1.0%) high severe
variance introduced by outliers: 26.750%
variance is moderately inflated by outliers
```

Ok, my system is really noisy, and shouldn't be used for serious benchmarking of things with similar numbers. But that hardly matters here. `shuffle2` is approximately 40x faster than `shuffle1` on a list with 1001 elements. Due to the differences between O(n) and O(n^2), that will only increase in with larger lists. I'm certain that whatever your test code was timing, it wasn't the shuffle algorithm.

Actually, I have a guess. Your version is lazy enough to return results incrementally. 5 seconds is a plausible period of time for getting the first few results, if you never touch the generator after the call to it. Maybe that's what's going on in your timing.

Comment: Thank you! (And thanks to others who commented above). As I said, I am new to Haskell, and it seems I simply made a huge noob mistake and overlooked the implications of the laziness. Tail between my legs and egg on my face, at least it all makes sense to me now.

Comment: @Tientuinë Well, it's a tough thing to learn. I hope you get something constructive out of my response, too. Check out the Criterion library. I didn't call it out specifically in my response, but it's really worth your time to learn it.

Comment: Criterion looks quite useful, glad it's on my radar now.